# DB connection made in using statement

Tags: c#, database

In here it shows the error,some invalid argument

MyCode

```
    static SqlConnection conDB = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SiteSqlServer"].ConnectionString);

[WebMethod, ScriptMethod]
    public static List<HomeImageSliders> GetHomeImageSliders()
    {
        List<HomeImageSliders> HomeImageList = new List<HomeImageSliders>();
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conDB)) //<-- In here it shows the error
            {

            }
```

Comment: What is the exception you are seeing? Please post it with a full StackTrace.

Comment: Paste the connection string located in the configuration file

Comment: So you want to new up a connection using a static connection you've already created, only to dispose it at the end of the using statement?  Because that's what you're attempting to do.

Comment: Well none of the overloads of `SqlConnection` constructor takes an object of SqlConnection, so what other error you expect ?

Comment: you are passing a sqlConnection as a parameter into the SqlConnection constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SqlConnection` does not have a constructor that takes another `SqlConnection`.  Plus having a static `SqlConnection` is not a best practice. I suspect you want:

```
// make the _connection string_ static, not the _connection_
static string conDB = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SiteSqlServer"].ConnectionString;

[WebMethod, ScriptMethod]
public static List<HomeImageSliders> GetHomeImageSliders()
{
    List<HomeImageSliders> HomeImageList = new List<HomeImageSliders>();
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conDB)) error
        {

        }
```

Answer (score 4):

This is because you made a static DB connection, and tried to use it in the `using`.

Here is how you can fix this:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SiteSqlServer"].ConnectionString)) {
    ... // Your code goes here
}
```

Also remove the declaration of `conDB` - it is unnecessary.

Comment: can't i assign to this section to another variable ? ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SiteSqlServer"].ConnectionString

Comment: @TechGuy Sure, you can make `static string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SiteSqlServer"].ConnectionString;`, and then write `using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connStr)) {...}`

Answer (score 1):

SqlConnection constructor accepts connection string, but not another SqlConnection.